# phpmyadmin, Как сделать так чтобы при изменении таблицы ПОЛ менялся значение в таблице СТУДЕНТ-строка ПОЛ

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

$connect=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    $db=mysql_select_db('soc_pasport');

```
$sname=$_POST['sname'];//имя
$fname=$_POST['fname'].//фамилия
$tname=$_POST['tname'];//отчество
$group=$_POST['group'];//группа
$date=$_POST['date'];//дата рожд
$gender=$_POST['gender'];//пол
$nation=$_POST['nation'];//нация
$disability=$_POST['disability'];//инваоидность
$place=$_POST['place'];//местный или нет
$oblast=$_POST['oblast'];//область
$how=$_POST['how'];//с кем живет 
$family=$_POST['family'];//семья
$how1=$_POST['how1'];// семья
$uchet=$_POST['uchet'];// на учете?

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        mysql_query("ALTER TABLE full_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO full_name(surname,name,third_name) VALUES('$sname','$fname','$tname')");
        mysql_query("ALTER TABLE student AUTO_INCREMENT=1");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO student(groupName,date,gender) VALUES('$group','$date','$gender')");


}
mysql_close;
```

Comment: когда я отправляю запрос для вложения в таблицу studen значения группы, даты  и пол, они не появляются в базе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не нужно:

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE full_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1");
```

Когда вы добавляете новую строку, ей автоматически присваивается новый номер, 1, 2, 3..

А вы каждый раз принудительно ставите на 1